ggraph: adjusting text label position on circular dendrogram
I have been stuck trying to figure out how to fix the label text position of a circular dendrogram. I have been following the code published here but can't figure out what the problem is.
This is what my circular dendrogram looks like at the moment:

But I am hoping to have the text labels appear like so:

How do I fix it? I have been following the code exactly.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
# PLOT 
ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_diagonal(colour="grey") +
  scale_edge_colour_distiller(palette = "RdPu") +
  geom_node_text(aes(x = x*1.15,
                       y=y*1.15,
                       filter = leaf,
                       label = name,
                       angle = angle,
                       hjust = hjust,
                       colour = group), size=2.7, alpha=1) +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf,
                      x = x*1.07,
                      y=y*1.07,
                      colour=group,
                      size=value,
                      alpha=0.5)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values= rep( brewer.pal(9,"Paired") , 30)) +
  scale_size_continuous( range = c(0.1,10) ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"),
  ) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-1.3, 1.3), y = c(-1.3, 1.3))

Below is the ggraph data.


> dput(mygraph) structure(list(75, TRUE, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 3, 10, 10, 11, 11, 5, 4, 3, 10, 2, 1, 7, 9, 4, 11, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 3, 2, 10, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3, 4, 9, 3, 2, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3,
10, 5, 5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 2, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 12, 3, 10, 5, 9, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5), c(4, 3, 11, 2, 9, 6, 5, 12, 7, 1, 10, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 16, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
15, 43, 28, 44, 15, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 15, 54, 55, 28, 48, 56, 57, 58, 16, 59, 60, 61, 62, 28, 59, 63, 64, 48, 16, 39, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 48, 18, 70, 46, 71, 72, 39, 59, 72, 73, 16, 48, 74 ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, list(c(1, 0, 1),
structure(list(), names = character(0)), list(name = c("origin", "Outdoor activities", "Domestic activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Agricultural activities", "Learning activities", "Health and wellbeing activities", "Musical activities", "Workshop
activities", "Entertainment activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Community activities", "Mechanical activities", "Bush walking", "Baking", "Manual arts and crafts", "Community gardening", "Historical sharing Q&A", "Clothing maintenance (sewing)",
"Wild life tours", "Carpentry", "Assisted guides (student companionship)", "Knowledge passing", "Palative awareness", "Community musical bands", "Parenting skills", "General workshops", "Community theatre", "Crochet and knitting", "Water aerobics", "Gentle
physical exercise", "Community diners (meals on wheels)", "Inala homework club", "Language club", "Photography", "Physical exercises (dance, gym, colour run)", "Pet daycare", "Trivia camp", "Music lessons", "Board games", "Growing vegetables", "Cooking
cafe", "Schools camps and day visits", "Painting and sipping", "Book club", "Composing music", "Woodworking", "Cake decorating", "Cooking", "Fitness training", "Students teaching IT", "Sharing traditional recipes", "Playing music", "Traditional dancing",
"Dragon's den (chicken eggs)", "Chess", "Card games", "Tutoring", "Playing musical instruments", "Painting", "Rehabilitation and physio", "Using technology (incl. social media)", "Reading together", "Video games", "Karaoke", "Putt putt", "Table tennies",
"Playing puzzles", "Walking together", "Watching sports on the television", "Learning mechanical work", "Water sports", "Story telling", "Interpretative painting", "Life skills"), value = c(0.585580174112692, 0.893185549415648, 0.26200358569622, 0.203951701987535,
0.488889964995906, 0.58272284292616, 0.512202943209559, 0.486715000122786, 0.0233161903452128, 0.725962040247396, 0.230725078377873, 0.0891078060958534, 0.601971111027524, 0.770974726416171, 0.112899012630805, 0.702898587333038, 0.716850318480283, 0.131957670208067,
0.65517760720104, 0.910050076199695, 0.095754484878853, 0.610197829082608, 0.0592852185945958, 0.822226302931085, 0.479145678458735, 0.460636418079957, 0.704600618453696, 0.521227885968983, 0.175805907929316, 0.640184475807473, 0.45457612676546, 0.507625086698681,
0.460464909672737, 0.791949789505452, 0.679316321620718, 0.956594054820016, 0.107164902845398, 0.13667330192402, 0.956593341659755, 0.416489312890917, 0.994603507919237, 0.465922170784324, 0.166321847587824, 0.625731714069843, 0.0725796180777252, 0.963703070301563,
0.42543631256558, 0.521754823392257, 0.574694129405543, 0.888251390540972, 0.956966195488349, 0.631142220227048, 0.81483043031767, 0.999659575987607, 0.817718225996941, 0.994496389990672, 0.354073196649551, 0.502177250571549, 0.377560483757406, 0.315485945204273,
0.7389785728883, 0.218990557361394, 0.346426092088223, 0.229574259370565, 0.538299076724797, 0.135757425567135, 0.236583026824519, 0.159444775199518, 0.915375969838351, 0.191791382618248, 0.747529144166037, 0.157402683980763, 0.537972879828885, 0.872691323980689,
0.482101482339203), group = c(NA, "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "origin", "Outdoor activities", "Domestic activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Agricultural activities",
"Learning activities", "Domestic activities", "Outdoor activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Outdoor activities", "Learning activities", "Health and wellbeing activities", "Musical activities", "Domestic activities", "Workshop activities", "Entertainment
activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Community activities", "Community activities", "Learning activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Domestic
activities", "Outdoor activities", "Musical activities", "Entertainment activities", "Agricultural activities", "Community activities", "Outdoor activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Learning activities", "Musical activities", "Arts and craft activities",
"Arts and craft activities", "Domestic activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Learning activities", "Domestic activities", "Musical activities", "Musical activities", "Agricultural activities", "Entertainment activities", "Entertainment activities",
"Learning activities", "Musical activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Learning activities", "Learning activities", "Entertainment activities", "Entertainment activities", "Entertainment activities", "Entertainment
activities", "Entertainment activities", "Outdoor activities", "Entertainment activities", "Mechanical activities", "Physical and fitness activities", "Learning activities", "Arts and craft activities", "Learning activities"), id = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L,
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L), angle = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 84.1935483870968, 78.3870967741936, 72.5806451612903, 66.7741935483871, 60.9677419354839, 55.1612903225806,
49.3548387096774, 43.5483870967742, 37.741935483871, 31.9354838709677, 26.1290322580645, 20.3225806451613, 14.5161290322581, 8.70967741935483, 2.90322580645162, -2.90322580645162, -8.70967741935483, -14.5161290322581, -20.3225806451613, -26.1290322580645,
-31.9354838709677, -37.741935483871, -43.5483870967742, -49.3548387096774, -55.1612903225806, -60.9677419354839, -66.7741935483871, -72.5806451612903, -78.3870967741935, -84.1935483870968, -90, 84.1935483870968, 78.3870967741935, 72.5806451612903, 66.7741935483871,
60.9677419354839, 55.1612903225806, 49.3548387096774, 43.5483870967742, 37.741935483871, 31.9354838709677, 26.1290322580645, 20.3225806451613, 14.5161290322581, 8.70967741935482, 2.90322580645159, -2.90322580645159, -8.70967741935482, -14.516129032258,
-20.3225806451613, -26.1290322580645, -31.9354838709677, -37.741935483871, -43.5483870967742, -49.3548387096774, -55.1612903225807, -60.9677419354838, -66.7741935483871, -72.5806451612903, -78.3870967741935, -84.1935483870968, -90), hjust = c(NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), structure(list(), names
= character(0))),
<environment>), class = "igraph")




It looks like you messed up the computation of the angle for the labels. To fix that I use some trigonometry to compute the angles on the fly based on the x and y positions of the nodes:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)

mygraph <- upgrade_graph(mygraph)

ggraph(mygraph, layout = "dendrogram", circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_diagonal(colour = "grey") +
  scale_edge_colour_distiller(palette = "RdPu") +
  geom_node_text(aes(
    x = x * 1.15,
    y = y * 1.15,
    filter = leaf,
    label = name,
    angle = ifelse(
      x >= 0,
      asin(y) * 360 / 2 / pi,
      360 - asin(y) * 360 / 2 / pi
    ),
    hjust = ifelse(
      x >= 0, 0, 1
    ),
    colour = group
  ), size = 1.3, alpha = 1, vjust = .5, color = "black") +
  geom_node_point(aes(
    filter = leaf,
    x = x * 1.07,
    y = y * 1.07,
    colour = group,
    size = value,
    alpha = 0.5
  )) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = rep(brewer.pal(9, "Paired"), 30)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.1, 10)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
  ) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-1.3, 1.3), y = c(-1.3, 1.3)) +
  coord_equal()


